# PHP - What does Warning: strpos() [function.strpos]: Empty delimiter in mean?

Tags: php

What does Warning: strpos() [function.strpos]: Empty delimiter in mean?

I have this:

```
    if(strpos('&#039;', $text) === false)
    {
        $text = str_replace('&#039;', "'", $text);
    }
```

Comment: Some context would help.

Comment: sorry, given the original lack of details, it's the best I could do

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At a guess, I'd say `$text` is an empty string (thanks Mark for pointing out the specifics)

Edit: Also, another guess is you have the parameters in the wrong order. The method signature of strpos is

```
int strpos ( string $haystack , mixed $needle [, int $offset = 0 ] )
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

Comment: specifically $text = "". $text = NULL will spimply return a false.

Comment: Found it. The preceding function doesn't check if text is empty :D Thanks Mark :D

Answer (score 2):

For starters you going about it all wrong....

- strpos may return a `false`,`""`,`0`
- the first argument must be the hastack
- the second argument should be the needle.

what you should do is:

```
if(false !== ($position = strpos($text,'&#039;'))) //Position Found and set in $position
{
    //$position holds the offset to the needle.
    $text = str_replace('&#039;', "'", $text);
}
```

petones

Comment: `strpos` returns boolean `FALSE` if the needle cannot be found

Comment: Qoute: "This function may return Boolean `FALSE`, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to `FALSE`, such as `0` or `""`."... Which is why I stated the comment!!!

Comment: To clarify, `strpos` will return integer 0 if the needle is the found at the first position in the haystack. So 0 == found, FALSE == not found. As the question states `=== false`, I'm guessing they only want to enter the branch if the needle is *not* found.

Answer (score 1):

TRY ADDING double quotes on the on the variable `$Text`

Change: `if(strpos('&#039;', $text)`

into: `if(strpos('&#039;', ".$text.")`

```
if(strpos('&#039;', ".$text.") === false)
    {
        $text = str_replace('&#039;', "'", $text);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this error after removing ?> from the end of the themes function.php in WP, but the error was only reported once.