# Warning: strpos() [function.strpos]: Empty delimiter

Tags: php

I have a plugin that uses strpos() method and on one site I'm getting this error

```
Warning: strpos() [function.strpos]: Empty delimiter. in /home/mysite/public_html/wp-includes/compat.php on line 55
```

Any ideas what the likely cause of this could be?

excerpt from compat.php

```
if (!function_exists('stripos')) {
function stripos($haystack, $needle, $offset = 0) {
    return strpos(strtolower($haystack), strtolower($needle), $offset);
}
}
```

My code...

```
function myFunction($thePost)
    {
        $theContent = $thePost->post_content;
        $myVar1 = array();
        preg_match_all('/<a\s[^>]*href=\"([^\"]*)\"[^>]*>(.*)<\/a>/siU',$theContent,$myVar1);
        $myVar2 = 0;
        foreach ($myVar1[1] as $myVar3)
        {
            $myVar4 = $myVar1[2][$myVar2];
            $myVar5 = FALSE;
            $myVar6 = get_bloginfo('wpurl');
            $myVar7 = str_replace('http://www.','',$myVar3);
            $myVar7 = str_replace('http://','',$myVar7);
            $myVar8 = str_replace('http://www.','',$myVar6);
            $myVar8 = str_replace('http://','',$myVar8);
            if (strpos($myVar3,'http://')!==0 || strpos($myVar7,$myVar8)===0) return TRUE;
            $myVar2++;
        }
        return FALSE;
    }
```

Comment: Post your php code please, we can't guess what you did with the function

Comment: And have you actually _looked_ at line 55 of /home/mysite/public_html/wp-includes/compat.php ? My psychic debugging skills are no match for Raymond Chen's but even I can figure out that's probably the best place to start :-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4105067/php-what-does-warning-strpos-function-strpos-empty-delimiter-in-mean

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something is passing an empty string as the second argument to Wordpress' implementation of `stripos()` (and it's not the code you've pasted above).

Can I ask why you a using PHP 4?

Comment: I just found out PHP4 does not support stripos. I'll wrap the function in a PHP version wrapper check

Comment: @Scott You don't have to, Wordpress has done it for you already.

Comment: You are right Phil, it was actually missing a parameter somehow.

Answer (score 0):

TRY ADDING double quotes on the on the variable

change this line:
  if (strpos($myVar3,'http://')!==0 || strpos($myVar7,$myVar8)===0) return TRUE;

into:
  if (strpos(".$myVar3.",'http://')!==0 || strpos(".$myVar7.",".$myVar8.")===0) return TRUE;